# 80s fantasy movie with tiny hunters. One uses a love potion and falls in love with a cat

Tags: story-identification, movie

My memory and google-fu are failing me in trying to remember the name of a fantasy movie from the '80s. The problem is that I can only remember two minor characters.

These two characters are tiny hunters, meaning that they are only a few inches tall. One of them wears a mouse pelt with the skull over the top of his head. Early in the movie they capture the Protagonist, but they are unable to keep him down because to them he is a giant.  They are afraid of cats, but at some point one of these hunters are hit with a love potion and falls in love with a cat.

That's about all I can remember about the movie and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is [**Willow**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096446/).

The characters you're describing are called brownies.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I was so focused on these two brownies that I could not remember the rest of the movie.

Comment: There you go, also, thank you for the subject edit.

Comment: @SparkeyG - [You're welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM).

Comment: You beat me to it, you stupid daikini.

Comment: @Omegacron - Ooh, I'm really scared. No! Don't! There's a- a peck here with an acorn pointed at me!

Comment: Mostly filmed in NZ, it was.