A fantasy movie with two races, "Big Ones" (=us) and smaller ones, about saving a newborn baby from a cruel queen
I watched this movie on French TV about 30 years ago. It was in French, but obviously dubbed from English.
There were two races (in the sense of Tolkien), Big people (us) and smaller people whose collective name I forgot. I am almost sure the name was not "dwarves", but something more original. But there were no special effects, these small people were played by actors affected with dwarfism.
The story was about a newborn baby who was heir of some country, and the cruel queen wanted of course to have him killed. I am not sure whether the queen herself had magical powers or not, but some people on her side certainly did.
The baby was eventually saved by an improbable alliance of priestesses, "big" fighters, at least one of which was an outlaw who joined the alliance more by necessity than good will, quite a few "dwarves" and a wizard. The latter reminded me of Gandalf from my memory of reading The Hobbit and LOTR, but that was before the movies were made for these works.

The first Lord of the Rings movie was in 1978.

Technically, you are right. I just checked: there was even a The Hobbit movie in 1977. Both, however, were animations. And I did not watch either of them. My knowledge of Gandalf, when I watched Willow, was based on reading, not watching a movie.

Technically: the best kind of right!

This is Willow (1988).

A young farmer is chosen to undertake a perilous journey in order to protect a special baby from an evil queen.


The story takes place in a medieval fantasy-style world populated by a variety of races, including Daikinis (average-sized people), Nelwyns (dwarf-sized people, portrayed by actors with real world dwarfism) and Brownies (Lilliputian-sized people), who each live in separate communities.
The plot revolves around the efforts of the evil Queen Bavmorda to capture and eliminate Elora Danan, a baby girl prophesied to dethrone and usurp her one day. Bavmorda is a sorceress and commands an army of soldiers, including her daughter, Sorsha, whom she sends to hunt down Elora.
The protagonist is Willow Ufgood, a young Nelwyn farmer who aspires to become the apprentice of his village's head sorcerer, the High Aldwin. Early on in the film, Willow rescues Elora from a river near his village, but soon realises she won't be safe there, and embarks on a journey to take her to the Daikini crossroads, accompanied by a few other Nelwyns.
Along the way, he gains more allies, including a rogueish swordsman named Madmartigan (the deuteragonist of the film), a pair of Brownies named Franjean and Rool, and a good sorceress named Fin Raziel.
The High Aldwin's role in the film is relatively small, as he stays behind in the Nelwyn village and isn't directly involved in Willow's quest.
A TV series set over twenty years after the events of the film aired in 2022, but was cancelled after one season.




Yes, that is it. Baby girl, not baby boy, but otherwise it fits all my memories. From your list of allies the wizard was absent, but I just checked: there is indeed a wizard called the High Aldwin.

I'll update my answer to better reflect the specifics of your question after I've had time to rewatch some of it.

Your answer was perfectly OK. It is just that I checked my own memory, to be sure it was not z false one.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153252/ but that one has far fewer details so I made this the dupe target.

@LogicDictates Your edited answer is great ! I had totally forgotten the brownies. And indeed High Alwin plays a small role, but my reading of The Hobbit was still rather fresh at the time and I made a connection with Gandalf, hence his presence was one of the details I did remember.

@Alfred - Thanks. I think I only watched the whole film once previously myself, decades ago, so I'd forgotten about both the Brownies and the High Aldwin. Upon rewatching it, I immediately recognised the High Aldwin's very distinctive voice as belonging to the same actor who played Gwildor in Masters of the Universe (1987). Incidentally, if you enjoyed the smaller actors in this film, I recommend checking out Time Bandits (1981), assuming you haven't already.
